# Python Selenium Options error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

пытаюсь запустить браузер в режиме headless, но выкидывает ошибку:

```
def init_driver():
    ff = "../install/chromedriver.exe"
    option = Options
    option.headless = True
    # chrome_option.add_argument("headless")
    # prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    # chrome_option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    try:
        # driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, options=option)
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, chrome_options=chrome_option, service_args=service_args)
    except SessionNotCreatedException:
        print("Ошибка инициализации браузера. Скорее всего у вас не установлен браузер. Пожалуйста обратитесь к разработчику парсера")

    return driver
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/www.vseinstrumenti.ru/parser.py", line 130, in <module>
    start_threading()
  File "D:/Git/www.vseinstrumenti.ru/parser.py", line 123, in start_threading
    for _ in executor.map(parsing, list_product):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 586, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:/Git/www.vseinstrumenti.ru/parser.py", line 109, in parsing
    driver = init_driver()
  File "D:/Git/www.vseinstrumenti.ru/parser.py", line 42, in init_driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, options=option)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 64, in __init__
    desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
TypeError: to_capabilities() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Раньше было то, что закоментировано, просто захотел сделать один метод для разных браузеров, но выкидывает ошибку

Answer (score 0):

надо вызвать конструктор:

```
option = Options()
```

иначе выходит, что в переменную options пишется сам класс, а не экземпляр